# $X_1,\dots , X_n$ are random variables then $X_1+\dots + X_n$ is also random variable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

**Question: $X_1,\dots , X_n$ are random variables then $X_1+\dots + X_n$ is also random variable. Prove this theorem for $n=2$  by showing that $\{X_1 +X_2 <x\}\in \mathcal{F}$,  $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$- algebra.**

Note that, $\{X_1 +X_2 <x\}= \{\omega:X_1(\omega) +X_2(\omega) <x\}$

The way I did it:

Consider $A(z)=\{X_1 <x-z\}$ and $B(z)=\{X_2 <z\}$  ,$z\in \mathbb{Q}$
$$A(z)\cap B(z) = \{\omega:X_1(\omega)<x-z, \text{ and }(\wedge)  X_2(\omega) <z\}\subset\{X_1 +X_2 <x\}$$

Then  $C=\cup_{z} [A(z)\cap B(z)]\subset \{X_1 +X_2 <x\}$

And  $C\supset \{X_1 +X_2 <x\}$  (Trivial since $\omega_0 \in \{X_1 +X_2 <x\}$  implies $\exists$ a $z\in \mathbb{Q}$  such that $X_1(\omega_0)<x-z$ and  $X_2(\omega_0)<z$ i.e. $\omega_0 \in A\cap B$  )

Now $A(z), B(z)\in \mathcal{F}\Rightarrow A(z)\cap B(z)\in \mathcal{F}\Rightarrow C \in \mathcal{F}$

Tnen $\{X_1 +X_2 <x\} \in \mathcal{F}$

Comment: You need to use countable operations; You can't just do the $\cup_z$ over the reals. Try rationals instead.

Comment: @copper.hat I changed $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it right now?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on the "trivial" part after this change, maybe.

Comment: @MANMAID: As Clement mentioned, the step marked Trivial needs more elaboration.

Comment: What are A and B here?

Comment: @ClementC. I explained the trivial part

Comment: @Did Obviously $A=\cup_{z} A(z)$ and $B=\cup_{z} B(z)$, you can also take $C=A\cap B$, and forget about $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Oh, so you think that $$\bigcup_z(A(z)\cap B(z))=\left(\bigcup_zA(z)\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_zB(z)\right)$$ right? Well then, exercise: Show by a simple example that the identity does not hold. Obviously.

Comment: @Did It holds for Two, why not for countable collection. I added a picture in a answer, since I had no choice.

Comment: ?? Choose unions over two indices $z=1$ and $z=2$, $A_1=B_2=X$, $A_2=B_1=Y$ then the LHS is $____$ while the RHS is $___$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Did I checked it, you are right, can you check the solution now if there is anything wrong!

Comment: Yes this is the usual approach.